# Вызов класса в ветвлении

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть вот такой класс для сохранения видео в aiogram, на данный момент могу его вызвать только по команде или по обычной кнопке через командно необходимо его вызывать в ветвлении if else

Вот сам класс

```
class FSMdonload(StatesGroup):
    video = State()
    idprofile = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands="Видеоответ", state=None)
async def fsm_donload_video(message: types.Message):
    await FSMdonload.video.set()
    test = message.text
    print(test)
    await message.reply('Нажмите на скрепку и запишите видеоответ')


# Ловим id video and id profile
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['video'] ,state=FSMdonload.video)
async def load_video(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['video'] = message.video.file_id
        data['idprofile'] = message.from_id
        # data['question'] = message.text
    await message.reply('Видео ответ принят')
    await sql_add_videobase(state)  # выводил в базу
    await state.finish()
```

А вот где его нужно вызвать

```
elif quantitystr > 1 and message.text == 'Вопрос №1' :
       await message.answer(*qwestion[0], reply_markup=nav.qwestionMenu_2)
```

Comment: Что вы хотите вызывать и зачем?

Comment: Вызвать хочу машину состояний из класса если в чат прилетит Вопрос №1

Comment: await FSMdonload.video.set() ?

Comment: Тоже подходит, спасибо.